# Writing sql query in linq syntax

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I'am trying to write the following query in linq syntax but i can make it. I'am getting errors at the marked line `Error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>.Contains(AnonymousType#1)' has some invalid arguments`
. How can i write it properly ?

sql:

```
     select * from [dbo].[TableOrder]
     where TableID not in (
     select tbl.TableID from [dbo].[TableOrder] tbl
     left join [dbo].[Restorant] r on tbl.RestorantID = r.RestorantID 
     left join [dbo].[Reservation] res on res.TableID = tbl.TableID
     where ReservationDate = '15.06.2014' and ResStartTime = '2100' and ResEndTime='2299')
```

linq:

```
            var query = (from t in db.TableOrderTbls.AsQueryable()
                     join r in db.RestorantTbls on t.RestorantID equals r.RestorantID
                     join res in db.ReservationTbls on t.TableID equals res.TableID
                     where (resv.RseservationDate == res.ReservationDate && resv.RestorantName == r.RestorantName) && ((Convert.ToInt32(resv.ResStartTime) < Convert.ToInt32(res.ResStartTime) &&Convert.ToInt32(resv.ResEndTime) < Convert.ToInt32(res.ResStartTime))||((Convert.ToInt32(resv.ResStartTime) > Convert.ToInt32(res.ResEndTime) && Convert.ToInt32(resv.ResEndTime) > Convert.ToInt32(res.ResEndTime))))
                     select new {r.RestorantName, r.RestorantID, t.TableID, t.TableType}).ToList();

        var q = from t in db.TableOrderTbls.AsQueryable()
                where query.Contains(t.TableID) // ERROR LINE
                select t;
```

Comment: Why not make the lives of those who'd like to help you by including the full error details in your question?

Comment: Now it makes sense. Your `select` is returning a new anonymous type, containing 4 properties. You are treating it as if it contains just 1 in your call to `query.Contains(t.TableID)`. Using your code as-is, you would need to pass your anonymous type to the `Contains` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your query object is a list of:

```
select new {r.RestorantName, r.RestorantID, t.TableID, t.TableType}
```

But you are trying to see if it contains a:

```
TableOrderTbls.TableId
```

An anonymous `{r.RestorantName, r.RestorantID, t.TableID, t.TableType}` is not the same type as an `TableOrderTbls.TableId`.

You need to be more specific in mapping your anonymous type to `TableOrderTbls.TableId`.

Wild guess here, try this:

```
where query.Any(x => x.TableID == t.TableID)
```

Comment: So it's compiling, running and not returning an error. Are you sure the data is good and it should be returning something? Put a breakpoint and inspect the results of query, then also break out the second query without the where, ToList() it and inspect. Make sure it even matches.

Comment: it is returning NotSupportedException

Comment: So initially when you tried my answer it returned null, but now it is returning a not supported exception? What changed?

Comment: I don't know, I'am just getting NotSupportedException and Any() function cause this.

Comment: Perhaps .Any is not supported... how about just adding db.TableOrderTbls to query and joining on TableId?

Comment: Use Eric's code and remove .ToList() from the first query.